# My fastapi server that connects to a database in the websocket view freezes

Tags: database, websocket, sqlalchemy, fastapi, chat

I have a project on fastapi to implement a chat between users with a record of messages in the database. I use fastapi.WebSocket and sqlalchemy to work with the database.

I noticed the server freezes, does not allow creating new connections via a websocket, no functions respond, and this remains even if you stop sending messages and its users will be disconnected from the server.

If I remove the functionality of writing to the database, then everything works well, without freezes.

Here below are the various server files.

main.py

```
# Database
from sqlalchemy.orm import Session
from db import get_db
# JSON Web Tokens
from jose import JWTError, jwt
# Security
from security import SECRET_KEY, ALGORITHM
# crud
import crud
# Views
from .views import home, socket

subapp = APIRouter()

# Dependency
def get_user(websocket: WebSocket, db: Session = Depends(get_db)):
    token = websocket.cookies.get("sessionid")

    if not token:
        return None

    try:
        token_data = jwt.decode(token, SECRET_KEY, algorithms=[ALGORITHM])
        user = crud.get_user_by_id(db=db, id=token_data["id"])

        if user == None or user.is_active == False:
            return None
        
        current_time = datetime.now()

        if datetime.strptime(str(token_data["validity_period"]), "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f") < current_time:
            return None

        return token_data["id"]

    except JWTError:
        return None


@subapp.websocket('/ws/')
async def socket_view(
    websocket: WebSocket,
    mobile: bool,
    id: int = Depends(get_user),
):
    return await socket.handle_socket(
        websocket=websocket,
        mobile=mobile,
        id=id
    )
```

socket.py

```
from fastapi import WebSocket, WebSocketDisconnect
import json
# Datetime
import time
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
import asyncio
from .socket_modules.ping import ping_handler
from .socket_modules.request import request_handler
from .socket_modules.request_query import request_query_handler
from .socket_modules.request_cancel import request_cancel_handler

class ConnectionManager:
    def __init__(self):
        self.active_connections = {}
    
connection_manager = ConnectionManager()

async def switch(id, msg, websocket):
    if msg['event'] == 'ping':
        await ping_handler(id, msg, websocket, connection_manager)
    elif msg['event'] == 'request':
        await request_handler(id, msg, connection_manager)
    elif msg['event'] == 'RQuery':
        await request_query_handler(id, msg, connection_manager)
    elif msg['event'] == 'request-cancel':
        await request_cancel_handler(id, msg, connection_manager)

# Websocket.
async def handle_socket(websocket: WebSocket, mobile: bool, id: int):
    # The connect function and some other methods have been removed so they don't
    # make the code overwhelming for this question, but they exists in the source
    await connection_manager.connect(id=id, websocket=websocket, mobile=mobile)
    try:
        while True:
            message = await websocket.receive_json()
            await switch(id, message, websocket)
    except WebSocketDisconnect:
        pass
    except:
        pass

# Start removing inactive connections.
asyncio.create_task(connection_manager.remove_inactive_connections())
```

request.py

```
# Datetime
from datetime import datetime
# Database
from db import SessionLocal
from sqlalchemy.sql import text
# Models
from models.user import User
from models.friend_request import Friend_Request
from models.user import Friendship
from models.blocked_user import Blocked_User

async def request_handler(fromID, msg, conMan):
    try:
        db = SessionLocal()
    except:
        db.close()
    else:
        # Start a nested transaction so the friend request table can be locked.
        db.begin_nested()
        db.execute(text("LOCK TABLE friend_requests IN ACCESS EXCLUSIVE MODE;"))
        # Get a friend request between these two.
        request = db.query(Friend_Request).filter(
            Friend_Request.sender_id.in_([fromID, msg['toID']]),
            Friend_Request.recipient_id.in_([fromID, msg['toID']])
        ).first()

        # Get a friendship entry between both users.
        friendship_entry = db.query(Friendship).filter(
            Friendship.user_id.in_([fromID, msg['toID']]),
            Friendship.new_friend_id.in_([fromID, msg['toID']])
        ).first()

        # Get a blocked user entry between both users.
        blocked_entry = db.query(Blocked_User).filter(
            Blocked_User.sender_id.in_([fromID, msg['toID']]),
            Blocked_User.recipient_id.in_([fromID, msg['toID']])
        ).first()

        # If any of these entry exists, exit.
        if request or friendship_entry or blocked_entry:
            pass
        else:
            sender = db.query(User).get(fromID)
            receiver = db.query(User).get(msg['toID'])
            
            current_time = datetime.now()
            request_obj = Friend_Request(
                sender_id=sender.id, sender_firstname=sender.firstname, \
                sender_lastname=sender.lastname, sender_username=sender.username, \
                time_sent=current_time, recipient_id=receiver.id
            )
            db.add(request_obj)

            message = {
                'event': 'request',
                'sender-id': sender.id,
                'sender-firstname': sender.firstname.title(),
                'sender-lastname': sender.lastname.title(),
                'sender-username': sender.username,
                'time': str(current_time),
                'confirmed': False,
                'deleted': False
            }

            await conMan.send_personal_message(msg['toID'], message)
        db.commit()
        # To close out the nested transaction
        db.commit()
        db.close()
```

I suspect the issue is caused by the handler functions such as 'request_handler' in the 'request.py' file that makes use of the code

```
try:
    db = SessionLocal()
except:
    db.close()
else:
     // All the database operations.

    db.commit()
    # To close out the nested transaction
    db.commit()
    db.close()
```

because when I remove the handler functions the server never freezes anymore but what am I doing wrong?
how do I access the database properly when a websocket message is received and passed to these handler functions?

I use the code snippet immediately above because that is what could be used in fastapi, is there a better way?

Comment: You might find [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71517830/17865804) helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I gess problem with sync session.
Try to switch to async db driver/lib, for example async sqlalchemy 2.0

https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/orm/extensions/asyncio.html

Comment: Thanks, but I think the issue was the locking of the friend_requests table, after removing all the locks the server never freezes anymore.